# Create live usb from ubuntu-14.04.4-server-amd64

Tags: 14.04, server, live-usb

I installed an Ubuntu Server Editition as a virtual machine and I am going to configure it.
Is there a way to create a live usb for it? Simply by extracting its current state and use it as a base for the live usb.
I looked for the Ubuntu Customization Kit but it does not seem to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm assuming you already saw this, right? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Comment: Thank you! I solved following the guide at this link: [LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch) . But now I have one last problem.. when I start the live system all the folders are duplicated, so for example I have : sys sys_1 tmp tmp_1 usr usr_1. Do you know why I have this problem? despite this the system works perfectly.

Comment: Are they real duplicates, or just symlinks?

Comment: ok.. I made a mistake.. for some reason I did 2 times the same command "sudo mksquashfs chroot image/casper/filesystem.squashfs" and this creates all the folders 2 times. Now everything it's ok! thank you for the help!